# Tailwindcss React Error, Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Assets/images/talentWorldWide.jpg',

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I don't know what's going on I am not even using this image anywhere but it still says Not found but it's there in the folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umVEH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANpbs.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd cut and paste the error messages into your question instead of linking to images.

Comment: Do you have a `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: Also, can you include the JSX file that's failing, `talent-world-wide.jsx`, as well as `src/index.css`?

Comment: Sure, No i don't have webpack.config.js, sure i will add those files, but somehow the error is fixed i deleted the assets folder and instead of using images from the folder i am using http images.

Comment: Avoiding assets folder is not a solution. I ran into same problem, validating path, debugging import rules, nothing worked. Btw, Error message is: ERROR in ./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css) 5:36-76 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '${plusImage}' in '/home/agassaa/codes/redux course/think-in-a-redux-way/Error/src'

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure you are using the correct path when linking for example:

```
./Assets/images/whateveryourimageis.jpg

or if your folder is up a directory level

../Assets/images/whateveryourimageis.jpg
```

Ensure that your paths are correct when linking, further information on the file containing the error and your file structure may help us give better guidance.